# Prove naturality of unit and counit in Tensor-hom adjunction

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, adjoint-functors

I am learning some basics from *Category Theory* and I am currently working on understanding **Tensor-hom** adjunction. I was reading a Wiki article about it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction), but I am confused about the following:

When we construct a unit and counit as there as following: The unit

$$\varepsilon : FG \to 1_{\mathcal C}$$
has components
$$\varepsilon_Z : Hom_S (X,Z) \otimes_R X \to Z$$
given by evaluation:
\begin{align*}
& \phi \in Hom_S(X,Z) \quad \textrm{i} \quad x\in X \\
& \varepsilon(\phi \otimes x) = \phi(x).
\end{align*}
And counit with components
\begin{align*}
    & \eta: 1_{\mathcal D} \to GF \\
    & \eta_Y : Y \to Hom_S(X, Y \otimes_R X)
\end{align*}
we define as
$$\eta_Y(y)(t) = y \otimes t \quad \textrm{for} \quad t \in X.$$
Counit and unit equations can now be easily checked. What about naturality? How to formally prove that these transformations are indeed natural? Also, I was wondering if it is true that evaluation is always a natural transformation.

My work on proving $\varepsilon$ is natural:
To prove this, we have to show the following diagram commutes:
[image]

But, I am not sure what exactly $FG(f)$ is (it's defined for objects, but what about arrows?) and how to prove that this commutes.

**Edit**: So, we have functors defined as
\begin{align*}
F(Y) &= Y \otimes_R X \quad \textrm{za} \quad Y \in \mathcal D \\
G(Z) &= Hom_S(X,Z) \quad \textrm{za} \quad Z \in \mathcal C
\end{align*}
And what we are looking for is $FG(f)$ where $f: Z \to Y$. In the definition of functor, we have that if $f: X \to Y$ then $F(f): F(X) \to F(Y)$. So it is not hard to conclude that
$$G(f) : Hom_S (X,Z) \to Hom_S(X,Y)$$
and
$$FG(f) : Hom_S(X,Z) \otimes_R X \to Hom_S(X,Y) \otimes_R X$$
Is this enough to prove that such a diagram commutes?

Comment: Have you tried proving naturality? What have you done so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @IsAdisplayName I've edited my question, so you can see where I am stuck.

Comment: Ah, good. First step forwards is to figure out  the action on morphisms of both $F$ and $G$. Well, we don't actually need to figure out both. We only need to figure out one. The easiest way to do this depends a bit upon your starting point. E.g., can we assume $Hom(V , W)$ has already been defined, independent of the adjunction?

Comment: @IsAdisplayName I've edited the question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: To see what $\operatorname{Hom}(X,f)$ is, you need to take morphism $s\colon X\to Z$ and somehow use $f\colon Z\to Y$ to produce a morphism $t\colon X\to Y$. How could you do it? Similarly, if you have simple tensor $z\otimes x\in Z\otimes X$, how could you produce tensor in $Y\otimes X$ using $f\colon Z\to Y$?

Comment: @Ennar for first we can say $s \mapsto s \circ f$, and for second I am not sure, maybe $z \otimes x \mapsto f(z) \otimes x$, where $x$ is fixed.

Comment: Yes, that's it for the first one. The second one is close, you don't have $x$ fixed, you can write that map as $f\otimes\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: @Ennar So, I have to prove that $f \circ \varepsilon_Z(\phi \otimes x) = \varepsilon_Y \circ FG(f) (\phi \otimes x)$. Left side is $f \circ \varepsilon_Z(\phi \otimes x) = f \circ \phi(x)$ and right is $\varepsilon_Y \circ FG(f) (\phi \otimes x) = \epsilon_Y \circ F(f \circ (\phi \otimes x))$, but here I am stuck.

Comment: Take a simple tensor $s\otimes x\in \operatorname{Hom}_S (X,Z) \otimes_R X$ and calculate both compositions.

Comment: @Ennar That is what I did with $\phi \otimes x \in Hom_S(X,Z) \otimes_R X$.  But I am stuck with  $\varepsilon_Y \circ FG(f) (\phi \otimes x) = \epsilon_Y \circ F(f \circ (\phi \otimes x))$. It can be more simplified as $\varepsilon_Y \circ F(f) \circ F(\phi \otimes x) $ but what next?

Comment: Oh, right side is $\varepsilon_Y \circ FG(f)(\phi \circ x) = \varepsilon_Y \circ (f(\phi) \otimes x) = f(\phi(x)) $ which is same as left side. Is this correct @Ennar ?

Comment: Yes. One side is $f(\phi(x))$ and the other is $(f\circ\phi)(x)$ which are equal.

Comment: @Ennar Your comments could probably serve as an answer

Comment: @FShrike, it's an easy exercise, so it was more important that OP gets to the answer themselves, but, sure, I typed it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put our discussion in the comments into an answer. $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$

First of all, let's write down how these functors act on morphisms. Let $f\colon A\to B$. Then, $\Hom(X,f)\colon \Hom(X,A)\to \Hom(X,B)$. So, we take some morphism $s\colon X\to A$ and need to produce morphism $\Hom(X,f)(s)\colon X\to B$ which we can do easily with composition $X\stackrel{s}{\to} A \stackrel{f}{\to} B$, i.e. $\Hom(X,f)(s) = f\circ s$.

For tensor product, note that given any two linear maps $f\colon A\to A'$ and $g\colon B\to B'$, map $h\colon A\times B\to A'\otimes B'$ defined by $h(a,b) = f(a)\otimes g(b)$ is bilinear, so by the universal property there is a unique linear map $f\otimes g\colon A\otimes B\to A'\otimes B'$ such that $(f\otimes g)(a\otimes b) = f(a)\otimes g(b)$. So, given $f\colon A\to B$, we need $f\otimes X\colon A\otimes X\to B\otimes X$ which we can define simply as $f\otimes\mathrm{id}_X$.

We are now ready to check naturality:

\begin{array}{cccc}
\Hom(X,A)&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! X &\stackrel{\epsilon_A}{\longrightarrow} &A &\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} &B\\
\qquad\qquad s&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! x &{\mapsto} &s(x) &{\mapsto} & f(s(x))
\end{array}

\begin{array}{cccc}
\Hom(X,A)&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! X &\stackrel{(f\circ-)\otimes\mathrm{id}_X}{\longrightarrow} &\Hom(X,B)&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! X &\stackrel{\epsilon_B}{\longrightarrow} &B\\
\qquad\qquad s&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! x &{\mapsto} &\qquad(f\circ s)&\!\!\!\!\otimes&\!\!\!\! x &{\mapsto} & (f\circ s)(x)
\end{array}

which are obviously equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great theorem:

Assume two categories $C$ and $D$ and a functor $G : D \to C$. Now, assume for each $c \in C$, we have a universal arrow $(d , \eta_d : c \to G d)$ from $c$ to $G$. Then we can construct a functor $F : C \to D$ such that $F \dashv G$.

Proof sketch: we define $F c$ to be the $d$ such that $ (d , \eta_c : c \to G d)$ is the universal arrow. For $f : c \to c;'$, we can define the action an morphisms as follows. We have a diagram:

[image: definitoin of G(f)]

Here, the dotted line is guarenteed to exist uniquely via the fact that $\eta_c$ is a universal arrow. We define $F(f)$ to be this dotted morphism. We of course must verify that the assignment we have defined actually assembles into a functor $F : C \to D$. I leave this to you. It is now immideate that $\eta : 1_C \Rightarrow G \circ F$. There is more to check to ensure that we have an adjunction. I leave this to you. $\square$

You can find this theorem in 4.6 of Riehl's category theory in context.

Now, lets use this theorem to solve your problem. You already have a functor $\hom(X , -)$. So we just need to prove that, for each vector space $W$, we have a universal arrow $W \to \hom (X , V)$. Further, since we want to show that $X \otimes -$ is the left adjoint, we need to have $V \equiv X \otimes W$.

You have already defined the universal arrow $\eta_W$. You just need to show that it is actually universal. Do you think you can take it from here? If not, I'll edit this answer to complete the proof.

Comment: This answer is a little misleading. It is necessary to also check that the functor "$V$" agrees with $X\otimes W$ both on objects *and* on arrows (up to isomorphism). But if we already have the functor $W\mapsto X\otimes W$ then the theorem about "we can create a functor..." isn't as useful

Comment: I don't want to be negative though. Until recently I viewed that "great theorem" as one of my favourites. At any rate, the OP specifically asked about checking naturality of $\eta$ and $\epsilon$, **not** about "is there an adjunction?" but rather about "do these data form an adjunction?"

Comment: @FShrike shouldn't we get that the functors must agree on morphisms, since we have uniqueness from the universal arrow? And the naturality follows from all this, right? I didn't really stress this point (so maybe I should edit and do that), but part of the power of the theorem is that it tells us the universal arrows assemble into a natural transformation. And similarly, we can get the arrows for the counit to assemble into a natural transformation

Comment: @FShrike out of curiosity, what changed recently, displacing this theorem from one of your favorites?

Comment: In the great theorem, $F(f)$ is defined to be the unique arrow making $GF(f)\eta=\eta f$. This obviously holds if $F$ is pre-defined as a functor for which $\eta$ is natural, *but* OP's very question was about why $\eta$ is natural. So, to do the work to see that $X\otimes(-)$ is the same as this created $F$ is to have to answer the OP's question directly *anyway*... I don't think there's a way around this, unless you have a specific recipe for calculating the unique arrows (which the OP probably should be told)

Comment: What changed recently is that I used to think it was an actual theorem; I had only seen a proof involving a lot of diagram chasing etc. however once the theorem is phrased from the "enriched" perspective it becomes quite obvious. To encode the idea of "$\eta$ is a universal arrow" is equivalent to saying $D(F(c),d)\cong C(c,G(d))$ naturally in $d$, from which it's not too hard to argue that $F$ uniquely lifts to a functor making these isomorphism natural in $c$